# Set navigation menu item active in Handlebars partial

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Currently, I am repeating code for my navigation menu on every single tab, but I want to use partials so there's no duplicate code.

This is what I am using (below), with the `active` class on a different list element depending on the file. Instead, I'd like to use a partial `{{> fruits-nav}}`, but I can't find any information on how I would set the `active` class depending on which file is including the partial.

```
<div id="table-nav-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="apple"><a href="{{id}}">apple</a></li>
        <li class="active orange"><a href="{{id}}">orange</a></li>
        <li class="mango"><a href="{{id}}">mango</a></li>
        <li class="pineapple"><a href="{{id}}">pineapple</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass data to a partial so you can do this in your partial:

```
<div id="table-nav-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="{{#if active_apple}}active{{/if}} apple"><a href="{{id}}">apple</a></li>
        <li class="{{#if active_orange}}active{{/if}} orange"><a href="{{id}}">orange</a></li>
        <li class="{{#if active_mango}}active{{/if}} mango"><a href="{{id}}">mango</a></li>
        <li class="{{#if active_pineapple}}active{{/if}} pineapple"><a href="{{id}}">pineapple</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and then pull it in like this:

```
{{> fruits-nav active}}
```

and just make sure `active` has he appropriate flag set for the current fruit.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/GesND/

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Just a question: would I be able to set the flag in the file template that pulls in the partial? I don't really want to add more complexity on the JS end unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: I suppose you could write your own helper to wrap the partial and then `{{fruits_nav "pineapple"}}`. Handlebars really isn't set up for manipulating data inside the templates, that sort of thing is supposed to be done outside the template.

Comment: Well I don't really need to manipulate data inside the templates. I have multiple files: apple, orange, mango, pineapple. So is there any way to do something like {{> fruits-nav active=apple}} inside of the apple template, and {{> fruits-nav active=mango}} instead of the mango template, etc, etc?

Comment: You can write your own helper to use instead of `{{> ... }}`.

Answer (score 12):

I think you can even make it slightly simpler and more readable:

```
<div id="table-nav-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="{{#if active.apple}}active{{/if}} apple"><a href="{{id}}">apple</a></li>
        <li class="{{#if active.orange}}active{{/if}} orange"><a href="{{id}}">orange</a></li>
        <li class="{{#if active.mango}}active{{/if}} mango"><a href="{{id}}">mango</a></li>
        <li class="{{#if active.pineapple}}active{{/if}} pineapple"><a href="{{id}}">pineapple</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and while rendering:

```
active: { pineapple: true }
```

Comment: I have been struggling with getting this done via jquery + css + node..thanks for the simple solution.